# Паттерны в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, шаблоны-проектирования

Мне приходилось слышать разные мнения касательно паттернов. Я говорю не о паттернах в Python, а о паттернах вообще. Что половину из них нужно бросить в топку, что книги о паттернах программирования нужно запрещать как экстремистскую литературу, что Visitor это не какой не паттерн, а "самый обычный костыль", что если тебе не нравится кандидат на должность - спроси его на знание какого-нибудь паттерна Bridge, и если не сможет схему нарисовать, то пускай идет в другое место. О паттернах, конечно, говорят и хорошее, но эту часть я опущу.

Мой вопрос: Необходимо ли знание паттернов, если пишешь на Python? Или это пережиток прошлого и Python достаточно гибок, чтобы не нуждаться в таких ухищрениях? Если же занать их стоит, то какие 5-10 стоит изучить в первую очередь?

Comment: Не необходимо, но полезно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ответа нужно разобраться в том, что такое паттерн проектирования. Для начала стоит избавить от англицизма - не "паттерн", а "шаблон". Потом выяснить значение слова "шаблон". Хороший программист, даже не изучая шаблоны проектирования, рано или поздно начинает сам писать шаблонный код. И не важно на каком языке он программирует. Так что вопрос в том, стоит ли вам изобретать велосипед самостоятельно или сэкономить время и силы, познакомившись с многолетним опытом множества программистов.

Comment: Я понял о чем вы. Можете посоветовать те 5-10 или хотя-бы 2-3 шаблона, которые с высокой степенью вероятности пригодятся ближайшее время? Под ближайшим временем я имею в виду самые распространенные в Python

Comment: @svmitin откуда же мне знать, что вам пригодится? Разве что мимо декораторов в Python точно не пройти.

Comment: @svmitin, прямо самый распространенный - итератор. В Python он настолько сильно врос в язык, что даже не задумываешься, что это какой-то шаблон проектирование, а воспринимаешь как должное.